# How can I position my table in the center of the page in css?

Tags: html, css, web

How can I center this table using css?
I have tried many ways on all sorts of websites but nothing seems to work.
It does not make ant sense why it is not working.
As stated before, it need its to be in the middle of the page on my website.
Someones help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Homework Tracker</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@200;300;400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <style>

        body{
            font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgb(248, 250, 251);
            display: inline-block;
        }

        table,tr,td,th{
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 900px;
          padding-bottom: 10px;
          padding-top: 10px;
          background-color: white;
          text-align: center;

    }

        .Table{
          filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1rem rgb(238, 238, 238));
          border: 0px white;
          border-radius: 16px; 
          overflow: hidden;
          width: 100%;
          display: inline-block;
          position: cen;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
        }


    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class = "Table">

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>9:00 AM - 9:45 AM</td>
          <td>Science<br><i>Gaeeni</i><br><b>Science Lab</b></td>
          <td>Mech<br><i>Perlman</i><br><b>Room 7</b></td>
          <td>Math<br><i>Perlman</i><br><b>Room 7</b></td>
          <td>Math<br><i>Perlman</i><br><b>Room 7</b></td>
          <td>Math<br><i>Cardillo</i><br><b>Room 9</b></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is on your css, `display: inline-block;`. Delete it on `body` and change it on `.Table` to `display: flex;`. And then add `justify-content:center` to your `.Table` css.

Answer (score 0):

You set `display: inline-block` to `body` and `.table`.
So your code didn't work.
I removed those properties, and used `display: flex; justity-content: center` to place the table on the middle.

You can do it by `width: 900px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to `.table`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Homework Tracker</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@200;300;400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <style>

        body{
            font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgb(248, 250, 251);
        }

        table,tr,td,th{
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 900px;
          padding-bottom: 10px;
          padding-top: 10px;
          background-color: white;
          text-align: center;
          border-radius: 16px;

        }

        .Table{
          filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1rem rgb(238, 238, 238));
          border: 0px white;
          border-radius: 16px; 
          overflow: hidden;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
        }


    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class = "Table">

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>9:00 AM - 9:45 AM</td>
          <td>Science<br><i>Gaeeni</i><br><b>Science Lab</b></td>
          <td>Mech<br><i>Perlman</i><br><b>Room 7</b></td>
          <td>Math<br><i>Perlman</i><br><b>Room 7</b></td>
          <td>Math<br><i>Perlman</i><br><b>Room 7</b></td>
          <td>Math<br><i>Cardillo</i><br><b>Room 9</b></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but now, the border radius does not work.

Comment: I edited my answer. I set `border-radius: 16px;` to the table, and now, it works.